# Unable to get VLookup Property of the WorksheetFunction Class

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a VLookup table to get the value of the variable `Lookup`. I am getting an error of "Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class" when I call the function. I believe where I am going wrong is the numbering of position, position being the column index, I dont know how to adjust the indexes for such a small chart. This is what the table look like. For all the cases in the table, I am checking if the `rate_value` falls within the parameter. So for < 50 I am looking for is `rate_value` is a number less than 50 same for 50 To 100, does `rate_value`fall in between 50 to 100.

[image: Table]

What I am trying to do is for each `rate_value` I need it to associate with the value in the table. So for instance, if `rate_value = 200`, then the value of ``` Lookup = 0.4``rate_value ``` is set as a global Double defined in other code that is not relevant.

This is what my code currently looks like.

```
Dim Lookup As Double, rate_value As Double, sweep_value_min As Long, sweep_value_max As Long 
Lookup = GetRate(rate_value)
Select Case rate_value
    Case Is < 50
        sweep_value_min = rate_value - Lookup
        sweep_value_max = rate_value + Lookup
    Case 50 To 100
        sweep_value_min = rate_value - Lookup
        sweep_value_max = rate_value + Lookup
    Case Is > 100
        sweep_value_min = rate_value - Lookup
        sweep_value_max = rate_value + Lookup
End Select
```

---

UPDATED:

```
Function GetRate(rate As Variant) As Double
Dim wbSrc As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, position As Long

Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Documents\LookupTable.xlsx")
Set ws = wbSrc.Worksheets("Rate")
Select Case rate
   Case Is < 50
       position = 2 
       GetRate = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rate, ws.Range("A1:B4"), position, False)
   Case 50 To 100
       position = 3
       GetRate = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rate, ws.Range("A1:B4"), position, False)
   Case Is > 100
       position = 4
       GetRate = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rate, ws.Range("A1:B4"), position, False)
   Case Is = ""
       ErrorMsg = "No rate value. Can be found. Check before running again."
End Select
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Try using `Dim mtch` `mtch = Application.VLookup(rate,...` instead of `GetRate = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rate,...`. In case of no match `WorksheetFunction` raises a fatal error, but `Application` does not. Then use `If not Iserror(mtch) then GetRate  = mtch`. When no match, it will return 0 (because of the function return type). If you change it in `Variant` you can use `Else`  GetRate  = "NA"`...

Comment: @FaneDuru but there is never a case when it will return 0. the number range is from 0 to infinity.

Comment: @BigBen I made an update comment that says when I change the position to 2 I still get the error.

Comment: If you've changed the postion to just be two, and you're still getting an error, that means `rate` was not found in cells A1:A4. Which makes sense. `VLOOKUP` will only find something if your `rate` is the literal values `<50`, `50 - 100`, or `> 100`.

Comment: @BigBen Ohh, that would be it since my test case has `rate = 200` is there a way to have it say be if rate falls into the range of `<50` , `50-100`, and `> 100` ?

Comment: Do you really need an `If...Then` block, a `Select Case` *and* a lookup table here?  That's your business rules encoded in 3 different ways...

Comment: FYI in `GetRate`, if `rate` is a Double, then you can't test for `rate = ""` - that will give you a type mismatch error.  In your first block of code `Case 50, 100` is testing if `rate_value` is equal to 50 or 100, not whether it's between 50 or 100.   `Case 50 to 100` would be needed for that.

Comment: If you could change the first column of your rate table to `{0;50;100}` then the formula to return the value becomes simpler: `=VLOOKUP(lookup_value,rate_table,2)`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I thought about that, but doesn't it fail for a rate of `100`, returning `0.4` when the desired result is `0.2`?

Comment: @BigBen you are correct. But just change the 100 to 100.000000001 or similar, depending on needed precision.

Comment: @TimWilliams Ok I can make the change from the `If ... Then` to `Select Case` like I have in my sub, however my lookup table would still be running into the error of defining which cell I want

Comment: @RonRosenfeld what do you mean by change 100 to 100.000001? `rate_value` will always be whole numbers no decimals

Comment: @TimWilliams I have updated my code according to your suggestions, yet I am still running into the same error of "Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class"

Comment: That way if lookup_value is 100, it will be less than 100.00001 and return 0.2 rather than 0.4

Comment: @RonRosenfeld for my lookup values I want one to be if `rate_value` is less than 50 so 49.99999 or smaller than it will be `0.1` if `rate_value` is greater than or equal to 50  and less than or equal to 100 then 'rate_value = 0.2' and then last is if it is greater than 100 it will be '0.4'

Comment: Yes, if you want to use `VLOOKUP` for your solution, just adjust your values in Column1 accordingly.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I would prefer not to have to enter `=VLOOKUP` into a specific cell if not necessary

Comment: I thought you were using VBA. Why would you be considering entering `VLOOKUP` into a worksheet cell?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Oh I can just replace `WorksheetFunction.VLookup` with `VLOOKUP` in my function? What purpose does this change provide? At the moment with my adjusted code above, I believe it is working. Its just my table is a bit off.

Comment: No. `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup` is what you use in VBA.  `VLOOKUP` would be if you were putting it in a worksheet. Purpose is to answer the question in your title about a problem with the Vlookup property of the worksheetfunction class.  The first step is to properly set up a table.  However, if you prefer not to use Vlookup, then don't. But consider a more explanatory title.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Ok, I just titled it the error that VBA was giving me when using my `WorksheetFunction.Vlookup`

Answer (score 1):

Untested but this is one way to do it if your lookup tables follow that same pattern:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim Lookup As Double, rate_value As Double, sweep_value_min As Long, sweep_value_max As Long
    '...
    '...
    If IsNumeric(rate_value) Then
        Lookup = GetRate(rate_value)
        sweep_value_min = rate_value - Lookup
        sweep_value_max = rate_value + Lookup
    End If
End Sub
    
Function GetRate(rate As Variant) As Double
    Const WB_PATH As String = "C:\Users\Documents\LookupTable.xlsx"
    Static data As Variant 'only need to read this once....
    Dim r As Long

    If IsEmpty(data) Then 'already read the data?
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With Workbooks.Open(WB_PATH, ReadOnly:=True)
            data = .Worksheets("Rate").Range("A2:B4").Value
            .Close False
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If

    If Len(rate) > 0 And IsNumeric(rate) Then
        For r = 1 To UBound(data)
            If CheckSpan(rate, data(r, 1)) Then 'does this meet the criteria?
                GetRate = data(r, 2) 'return the value from that row
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next r
    Else
        'ErrorMsg = "No rate value. Can be found. Check before running again."
    End If
End Function

'does the value `v` fall inside the range specified by `span` ?
Function CheckSpan(v, ByVal span) As Boolean
    Dim arr
    span = Replace(span, " ", "") 'remove any spaces
    'handles cases <=, >=, <, >, X-Y
    Select Case True
        Case span Like "<=#*": CheckSpan = v <= CDbl(Right(span, Len(span) - 2))
        Case span Like ">=#*": CheckSpan = v >= CDbl(Right(span, Len(span) - 2))
        Case span Like "<#*": CheckSpan = v < CDbl(Right(span, Len(span) - 1))
        Case span Like ">#*": CheckSpan = v > CDbl(Right(span, Len(span) - 1))
        Case span Like "*#-#*"
            arr = Split(span, "-")
            CheckSpan = (v >= CDbl(arr(0)) And v <= CDbl(arr(1)))
    End Select
    Debug.Print v, span, CheckSpan
End Function

'for testing CheckSpan
Sub TestCheckSpan()
    CheckSpan 44, "<=50"
    CheckSpan 50, "<=50"
    CheckSpan 100, "<=50"
    CheckSpan 44, "<50"
    CheckSpan 50, "<50"
    CheckSpan 100, "<50"
    CheckSpan 45, "50 - 100"
    CheckSpan 105, "50 - 100"
    CheckSpan 55, "50 - 100"
    CheckSpan 100, "50 - 100"
End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate your efforts in this answer, however, when running this macro, there is no guarantee what the `rate_values` will be, so I cannot format my code to appear like yours does in `Sub TestCheckSpan`

Comment: So what other types of lookup column values do you have besides the ones you show?  You have "<X", ">X" and "X-Y".  What else?  Just numeric values with no modifiers or ranges?

Comment: Those are the column values, I think I was able get the function I posted to work when the table is set up differently, I have posted it in my updated question

Comment: Isn't the real aim to have the logic/mapping entirely in the table though?  The way you have it in your update you may as well refer to specific ranges on the sheet for each value.

Comment: Oh so you mean to remove the position lines as they hard-code the column index of the desired cell? I just am struggling to understand your answer above

Comment: `CheckSpan` is just a way to have your code check whether a numeric value meets one of the conditions listed in the first column of your lookup table.

Comment: Like an advanced error handling function?

Comment: No, not really.

Comment: ...it kind of does what you'd do if you have to scan the lookup table manually to find the correct row: compare to rate value with the cutoffs in the first column.

Comment: Oh, but is that necessary for what I am doing? Wouldnt it already "scan" the table to find the value?

Comment: It's a way for you to use a lookup table with the actual ranges you're interested in.  Your current "update" is harder to maintain because the logic is split/duplicated between the table and your VBA.  This approach puts all the business rules in the lookup table and is more generic: you could have a lookup table with 20 ranges and it would work the same way.

Comment: Ok I appreciate your help, unfortunately I will have to look for a different solution as I am unable to follow and implement how your code operates.